# Vim: turn Diacritics On with Vim-latex-suite

Tags: vim

The Vim-latex suite mentions that the Tex_Diacritics is off by default. I want to turn it on, how?

```
g:Tex_Diacritics                                           ls_11_3_7 ls_a_df
                                                                Tex_Diacritics


Type             Boolean
Default Value    0

Whether or not you want to use diacritics [ls_a_bw].
```

Also

> ```
> These mappings speed up typing European languages which contain diacritic
> characters such as a-umlaut etc.  >
>
> +<l>     expands to \v{<l>}
> =<l>     expands to \'{<l>} where <l> is an alphabet.
> ```
>
> >
>
> ```
> +}       expands to \"{a}
> +:       expands to \^{o}
> ```

**Perhaps related**

1. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49304/how-to-enable-vims-latexsuite-on-all-kind-of-documents-or-manually

Comment: ...if someone knows some chat-room where to ask this kind of simple questions, please, let me know. It is probably some `:toggle ls_a_bw` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a global variable, so you need:

```
:let g:Tex_Diacritcs=1
```

Also, that might be better included in your vimrc file so it's sourced at the correct moment.

Comment: Please, contain some small example like `u with two dots`, cannot for some reason get anything working even with the setting.